# How to check if ufw is running programmatically

Tags: command-line, ufw

In most services (e.g. privoxy) there is a clean way to get the service status:
`ps -C [servicename]`
Then by checking the exit code `($?)`: 0: the service was running 1: not running
This is not the case in ufw (not recognized as a service?)
The `sudo service ufw status` always exits with 0 whether ufw was running or not.
Any suggestions to get ufw programmatically through the exit code of the command used to check ufw status?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the exit code returned by `sudo ufw status` is always 0 you just need to `grep` for the status value:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
$ sudo ufw status | grep -qw active
$ echo $?
1
```

To work correctly you have to use the `-w` option, from `man grep`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

`-q` is just the quiet mode, nothing is written to standard ouput

Answer (score 1):

To check the status of UFW use

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

The output is similar to

```
my@machine:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for youruser:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip
```

Comment: Yes but I want to get the result (running / not running) through the exit code, i.e. by passing $? to the command line. In the proposed solution, the exit code is 0 in both cases.

Comment: Come on, do some research on your own: Add `grep active`and check the exit code. If `grep` does not find the searchword, it's exit code is 1.